# Is it possible to use ToolStrip Controller as TabMenu in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

i am new at VB.net.. i am making one Application for my friend. but i have one problem while using toolstrip...
i want to use toolstrip menu as tabmenu... like if i select any button from toolstrip menu, than form content change..just like while we change tab then form content will change which is inside that tab...is it possible to do so?

I don't have any code at the moment so i can not attach it..i have tried googling my problem but i didn't found any solution of this problem...hope you guys understand my problem..thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, for each "tab" you could create a panel on your form and set the Visible property of each to False. Then for each button click event in your ToolStrip, you could make them all Visible=False apart from the one you want to show.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Panel1.Visible = False
        Panel2.Visible = False
        Panel3.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub ToolStripButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton1.Click
        Panel1.Visible = True
        Panel2.Visible = False
        Panel3.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub ToolStripButton2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton2.Click
        Panel1.Visible = False
        Panel2.Visible = True
        Panel3.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub ToolStripButton3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton3.Click
        Panel1.Visible = False
        Panel2.Visible = False
        Panel3.Visible = True
    End Sub
End Class
```